# How do I search two columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with First Name, Last Name and Contact Number.

If user enters `kar`, then I want a full list with results containing `kar` in the First name or Last Name.

Comment: What do you mean by "optimized"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that `kar` is a portion of a name, if it is the full name, then do `first_name = 'kar'`

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, number
FROM your_phone_book
WHERE first_name LIKE '%kar%'
   OR last_name LIKE  '%kar%'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really rather simple:

```
SELECT * FROM directory
WHERE firstname LIKE '%kar%'
OR lastname LIKE '%kar%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select firstname from table
where firstname like '%name%'
```